# How can I dynamically create HTML DOM base on my JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have an accordion

[image]

Click on View Report, it expands

[image]

All data on this accordion, table, and piechart came from 1 object of my JSON Ajax call.

if I have 3, 5, or 10 objects, I want to dynamically create my accordions.

How do I do something like that ?

**HTML**

```
<br><br>

<div class="row student-accordion ">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="row panel-heading">

         <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 sa-section" >

           <span class="sa-h5" id="as-report-type-car"></span> <br>
           <span class="sa-h1"  id="as-section-num" class="section-num"></span><br>
           <span class="sa-h5" id="as-report-type-cdr"></span>

           <!-- <span class="as-cb-div"><span id="as-section-num"></span></span> -->

         </div>


         <!-- Title -->
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
           <span class="sa-h3" id="as-report-type-title" >
             <span id="as-section-num"></span>
           </span>
           <br>
           <span class="sa-h5" id="as-assignment" ></span> <br>
           <span class="sa-h4" id="as-date"></span>
         </div>


         <!-- Answers -->
         <div class="sa-right-items text-center">
           <span class="sa-answer"><br>
            <span> <span class="sa-h2">
              <span id="as-correct-num" ></span>/<span id="as-correct-total-num"></span>
            </span> <br> <span class="sa-h6">ITEMS ANSWERED <br> CORRECTLY</span> </span>
          </span>


          <!-- Score -->
          <span class="sa-score">
              <span class="sa-h2" id="as-avgscore"></span>% <br>
              <span class="sa-h6">SCORE</span>
          </span>


          <!-- Review -->
          <span class="sa-review">
            <img width="40px" src="/BIM/resources/images/icons-report/review_white.png"><br>
            <span> <span class="sa-h6">REVIEW</span> </span>
          </span>


          <!-- Report -->
          <span class="sa-report" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#as-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true"  class="pull-right">
            <img class="sa-report-btn" width="35px" src="/BIM/resources/images/icons-report/report_white.png"><br>
            <span><span id="view-report-btn" class="sa-h6 sa-report-btn">VIEW REPORT</span></span>
          </span>


          <!-- Hide -->

          <span class="sa-hide hidden"  data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#sa-collapse" aria-expanded="false"  class="pull-right">
            <img class="sa-hide-btn" width="35px" src="/BIM/resources/images/icons-report/hidedetails_white.png"><br>
            <span><span class="sa-h6 sa-hide-btn">HIDE DETAILS</span></span>
          </span>

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div id="as-collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">

       <!-- percent-item -->
       <%@ include file="../../components/teacher/percent-item.jsp" %>

       <div class="report-grid-area"></div>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.student-accordion .panel {
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.student-accordion .panel-heading {
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #4D8FCB;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.student-accordion .panel-body {
  background-color: white;
}
.student-accordion .panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body,
.student-accordion .panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .list-group {
  border-top: none;
}
.student-accordion .sa-h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.student-accordion .sa-h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}
.student-accordion .sa-h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}
.student-accordion .sa-h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.student-accordion .sa-h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
}
.student-accordion .sa-h6 {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: "adelle-sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}
.student-accordion .sa-right-items {
  float: left;
  margin: -20px 0px;
}
.student-accordion .sa-answer,
.student-accordion .sa-score,
.student-accordion .sa-review,
.student-accordion .sa-report,
.student-accordion .sa-hide {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 22px;
}
.student-accordion .sa-report,
.student-accordion .sa-hide {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.student-accordion .sa-hide-btn,
.student-accordion .sa-report-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.student-accordion .sa-section {
  text-align: center;
}
.student-accordion .sa-section:after {
  content: "";
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 96px;
  top: -10px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery', 'moment'], function($, moment) {

    $(function() {

        // Teacher Report
        var report_type_car   = $('#as-report-type-car');
        var report_type_cdr   = $('#as-report-type-cdr');
        var report_type_title = $('#as-report-type-title');

        var section_num       = $('#as-section-num');
        var problem_set       = $('#as-problem-set');
        var start_time        = $('#as-start-time');
        var due_time          = $('#as-due-time');
        var submit_am         = $('#as-submit-am');
        var submit_total      = $('#as-submit-total');
        var avg_score         = $('#as-avgscore');
        var danger            = $('.pc-danger');
        var warning           = $('.pc-warning');
        var success           = $('.pc-success');
        var danger_list       = $('.pc-danger-list');
        var warning_list      = $('.pc-warning-list');
        var success_list      = $('.pc-success-list');
        var student_am        = $('#as-student-am');
        var student_total     = $('#as-student-total');

        // Student Accordion
        var assignment        = $('#as-assignment');
        var date              = $('#as-date');
        var correct_num       = $('#as-correct-num');
        var correct_total_num = $('#as-correct-total-num');

        // Assignment SUmmary
        var students_div      = $('.as-students-div');
        var student_div       = $('.as-student-div');

        // Student Report
        var student_name      = $('#as-student-name');

        //SE Report Nav
        var btn_ap            = $('#btn-ap');
        var btn_rmd           = $('#btn-rmd');

        // Percent Piechart
        var percent_item      = $('.percent-item');
        var percent_skill     = $('.percent-skill');


        // Set this temporary until the BE for it is ready
        var beTeacherNotDone  = ['student', 'standard'];
        var beStudentNotDone  = ['section-exercise', 'course-benchmark', 'chapter-quiz', 'chapter-test', 'practice-test'];


        function getReportTitle() {

            var segmentArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
            var segment_4 = segmentArray[4];
            var segment4Array = segment_4.split('-');
            var newTitle = segment4Array[0] + " " + segment4Array[1];

            return newTitle;

        }

        getReportTitle();


        function updateReportHeaderBaseOnURL() {

            if (lastSegment === 'student') {

                btn_ap.addClass("hidden");
                btn_rmd.addClass("hidden");
                percent_skill.detach();

                student_div.show();
                students_div.hide();

            } else if (lastSegment === 'assignment') {

                btn_ap.removeClass("hidden");
                btn_rmd.removeClass("hidden");
                btn_ap.addClass("rn-btn-active");
                percent_skill.detach();
                student_div.hide();
                students_div.show();

            } else if ( $.inArray(lastSegment, beStudentNotDone) ) {
                percent_skill.detach();
            } else {

                btn_ap.removeClass("hidden");
                btn_rmd.removeClass("hidden");
                btn_rmd.addClass("rn-btn-active");
                percent_item.detach();
                student_div.hide();
                students_div.show();

            }

        }

        updateReportHeaderBaseOnURL();


        // console.log(window.rel_path+"teacher/report/"+lastSegment+"/"+lastSegment);

        btn_ap.click(function() {
            // btn_ap.href(href);
        });

        btn_rmd.click(function() {
            // btn_rmd.href(href);
        });




        function parseUrl(url) {
            var urlParamSplit = url.split("?");

            if (urlParamSplit.length !== 2) {
                return "InvalidUrlNoParamsSet";
            }

            var paramsList = urlParamSplit[1].split("&");
            if (paramsList.length < 1) {
                return "InvalidUrlNoParamsFound";
            }

            var paramsObj = {};
            paramsList.forEach(function(item) {
                var keyValueArray = item.split("=");
                paramsObj[keyValueArray[0]] = keyValueArray[1];
            });

            return paramsObj;
        }

        var href = location.href;
        var params = parseUrl(href);
        var lastSegment = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
        var assessmentId, classroomId;

        function setAjaxEndpoint() {

            if ($.inArray(lastSegment, beTeacherNotDone) || $.inArray(lastSegment, beStudentNotDone)) {
                lastSegment = 'assignment'; // Use this one for now
            }
        }

        setAjaxEndpoint();

        function setDataParams() {
            if ((params.assessmentId || params.classroomId) === undefined) {

                //Set this temporary while waiting for BE to be ready
                assessmentId = "206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3";
                classroomId = "722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a";

            } else {

                assessmentId = params.assessmentId;
                classroomId = params.classroomId;
            }
        }

        setDataParams();

        $.ajax({

            url: "/BIM/rest/report/" + lastSegment,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                assessmentId: assessmentId,
                classroomId: classroomId
            },

            success: function(objects) {

                function updateAssignmentSummary(x) {

                    var header = objects.assignments[x].header;
                    var name = objects.assignments[x].name;
                    var car, cdr, report_type_full;

                    // Check for space in report_type
                    if (header.report_type.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {

                        if (getReportTitle() === "Section Exercise") {
                            report_type_full = header.report_type.split(/(\s+)/);
                            car = report_type_full[0];
                            cdr = report_type_full[2];
                        } else {
                            report_type_full = getReportTitle().split(" ");
                            car = report_type_full[0];
                            cdr = report_type_full[1];
                        }

                        report_type_car.html(car);
                        report_type_cdr.html(cdr);
                        report_type_title.html(car + " " + cdr + " " + header.section_num);

                    } else {

                        car = header.report_type;
                        report_type_car.html(car);
                        report_type_title.html(car + " " + header.section_num);
                    }

                    section_num.html(header.section_num);
                    problem_set.html(header.problem_set);

                    // Not show date if summary
                    if (name === "Summary") {

                        start_time.html(" ");
                        due_time.html(" ");

                        $("#as-due-time-div").hide();
                        $("#as-start-time-div").hide();

                    } else {

                        $("#as-due-time-div").show();
                        $("#as-start-time-div").show();

                        start_time.html(moment(parseInt(header.start_time)).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));
                        due_time.html(moment(parseInt(header.due_time)).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));
                    }

                    // For Student
                    if (header.student_name) {
                        student_name.html(header.student_name);
                    }

                    student_am.html(header.student_am);
                    student_total.html(header.student_total);
                    submit_am.html(header.submit_am);
                    submit_total.html(header.submit_total);
                    avg_score.html(header.avg_score);

                    // Temp
                    assignment.html("ALGEBRA 1 ");
                    date.html("2/10/2015");
                    correct_num.html("8");
                    correct_total_num.html("20");

                    danger.html(header.danger);
                    warning.html(header.warning);
                    success.html(header.success);

                    danger_list.html(header.danger_list);
                    warning_list.html(header.warning_list);
                    success_list.html(header.success_list);

                }


                function updatePercentPieChart() {
                    var data = {};
                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

                    var options = {
                        width: 160,
                        height: 160,
                        chartArea: {
                            left: 10,
                            top: 20,
                            width: "100%",
                            height: "100%"
                        },

                        colors: ['#F46E4E', '#F9C262', '#ADB55E', ],
                        legend: 'none',
                        enableInteractivity: false,
                        pieSliceText: 'none',

                    };


                    // Gather all the data
                    $.each(objects.assignments, function(i, v) {

                        var header = v.header;
                        var total = header.danger + header.warning + header.success;

                        data[i] = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

                            ['Piechart', 'Number of Skills'],
                            ['danger', (header.danger / total) * 100],
                            ['warning', (header.warning / total) * 100],
                            ['success', (header.success / total) * 100],

                        ]);

                    });


                    // Populate the dropdown-menu
                    $.each(objects.assignments, function(i, v) {
                        var name = v.name;
                        var assignmentId = v.assignmentId;

                        // Auto Populate the dropdown-menu
                        $("#as-dd.dropdown").append('<option value="' + assignmentId + '">' + name + '</option>');

                        // Dropdown-menu change
                        $('#as-dd').on('change', function() {
                            var i = $('option:selected', $(this)).index();
                            updateAssignmentSummary(i);
                            chart.draw(data[i], options);
                        });

                    });


                    // Initializing
                    updateAssignmentSummary("0");
                    chart.draw(data[0], options);

                }

                // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
                google.load("visualization", "1", {
                    packages: ["corechart"]
                });

                google.setOnLoadCallback(updatePercentPieChart());

            }

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: I suggest you use Angular to bind data to the DOM. This way you can change the data and the elements automatically update. If you build the DOM elements with jquery, then you have to manually change elements when the data changes.

Comment: Depending on how big the application is Angular might not be nessesary, I find that it, while very useful, is only so in very large applications, and can end up being cumbersome

Answer (score 1):

json can be read as objects, just use a for loop to iterate through the object array and create elements that way.

Comment: I never done that before, do you mind at least give me a starter code, or provide me a little more hints. I appreciate your concern.

Comment: Can I have an example of what json is being returned? Then I can try build something a little more specific.

Comment: This might not be 100% legit, but as of right now, I load mine from this one. It will be similar to the final one - after BE guys finished it. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4e5cb1150dc45d53f779130da6031ab7

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to keep in mind is that JSON, in JavaScript, should be treated as an regular `Object` Keeping that in mind let's say you got something like this from your AJAX call:

```
{
 "average_grade": "B-",
 "teacher": "Mrs. Yeltson",
 "roster": 26
}
```

Now looking at your code, I would advise that you implement a templating solution. (It's not as bad as it sounds)

What we will do is label everything that should have the content will a special attribute `for=teacher`, like so:

```
<h1><span for="teacher">Loading...</span>'s Class</h1>
<h4>Class of <span for="roster">Loading..</span></h4>
<p>Averages a <span for="average_grade">Loading...</span></p>
```

And then when you get the results of the call, just fill in the `span` with the proper value:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.school.k12.us/api/class", function(data) {
   for(res in data) {
     $("[for="+res+"]").each(function() {$(this).text(data[res])})
   }
})
```

And Volia! Now you have a templated way to fill in values from an AJAX call.

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thanks man. At least is something. I never used `for` before, but I will use your answer as my reference for this. :D

Comment: How comes, you don't use `append()` , `html += ""`, or anything like that - Just curious ?

Comment: In the last code block, I am using `.text()` to set the text, this is so you can have a Loading message inside the `span` as shown

Comment: `jQuery(document.createElement('p')).appendTo('body'); //adds an empty p element 
to the page`

Comment: @开发人员 The purpose of the final code block is to fill in the text of the template spans filled in, so creating new elements in not nessesary

Comment: Your solution is  kind of cool for replacing the texts in side the dom, but can you also suggest me, I want to create those doms also on the fly, not just the texts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83694/discussion-between-speedyninja-and-).

Comment: Because eventually, I will need to create the whole accordion on the fly. I'm not sure  where to start. :(